# Filter out values that are equal on the same row?

Tags: arrays, powershell, string-comparison, dbatools

I've just run

```
Get-DbaDbQueryStoreOption -SqlInstance <MySQLServer> | 
Where ActualState -ne DesiredState | 
Select Database, ActualState, DesiredState
```

My intention was to get all rows from `Get-DbaDbQueryStoreOption` where `ActualState` and `DesiredState` were not identical. To my surprise, this returned rows where `ActualState` and `DesiredState` were identical.

Is my PowerShell somehow in error or is this a bug in `Get-DbaDbQueryStoreOption`?

I believe that this question makes sense even if you know nothing of the `Get-DbaDbQueryStoreOption` command from the dbatools module. However, the type of `ActualState` and `DesiredState` is `Selected.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.QueryStoreOptions`.

Comment: @Olaf The "Definition" columns don't hold the same value. One contains "ActualState" and the other contains "DesiredState".

Comment: @Olaf "Name" also doesn't match, but I wouldn't expect it to.

Comment: @Olaf They're both `Selected.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.QueryStoreOptions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `DesiredState` too refers to a *property of each input object*, replace
`Where ActualState -ne DesiredState` with:

```bash
Where { $_.ActualState -ne $_.DesiredState }
```

Your attempt to use [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax) cannot work, because the RHS of an operator such as `-ne`, which binds to the `-Value` parameter of [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object), must either be a *literal*, a *variable reference* or an *expression*, and none of them are able to refer to the *current pipeline input object* via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_), as the latter is only available inside [*script blocks*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks).

Due to [argument-mode parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#argument-mode), `DesiredState` in your attempt was interpreted as a bareword *string literal*, i.e. your attempt was equivalent to
`Where ActualState -ne 'DesiredState'`

Thus, as shown above, a *script block* must be used, in which `$_` can be used to refer to the current pipeline input object at will, which binds to the `-FilterScript` parameter.

---

##### The limitations of *simplified syntax*:

The **price you pay for the syntactic convenience of the alternative, [*simplified syntax*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax) offered by the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) and [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlets** is:

- You're **limited to *one* operation** (use of *one* operator, property reference or method call); e.g, you cannot *combine* multiple operations, such as with `-or` or `-and`; for the latter, you must use a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks), inside of which no constraints apply.
- That one **operation is limited to**:

  - `Where-Object`:

    - **Comparing a *property***<sup>[1]</sup> of each pipeline input object to **an *external value*** (i.e., the comparison operand cannot also refer to the input object); e.g.:

      ```bash
      # Same as:
      #   'ab', 'cde' | Where-Object { $_.Length -eq 3 }
      'ab', 'cde' | Where-Object Length -eq 3  # -> 'cde'
      ```
  - `ForEach-Object`: Referencing a *member* of each pipeline input object, i.e. one of the following:

    - **Getting** the **value of a *property***.

      ```bash
        # Same as:
        #   'ab', 'cde' | ForEach-Object { $_.Length }
        'ab', 'cde' | ForEach-Object Length  # -> @(2, 3)
      ```
    - **Invoking a *method* with *external values*** as arguments.

      ```bash
        # Same as:
        #   'ab', 'cde' | ForEach-Object { $_.Substring(1) }
        'ab', 'cde' | ForEach-Object Substring 1  # -> @('b', 'de')
      ```
- Simplified syntax **uses [argument-mode parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#argument-mode)**, which implies:

  - **Simple *strings*** may *optionally* be passed as ***barewords*** (not enclosed in quotation marks) - though you're free to use PowerShell's usual [string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules), as you *must* do in [expression-mode parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#expression-mode); e.g.:

    ```bash
     # Same as:
     #   @{ prop='ab' }, @{ prop='cde' } | Where-Object { $_.prop -eq 'ab' }
     # Note that 'ab' needn't be quoted.
     @{ prop='ab' }, @{ prop='cde' } | Where-Object prop -eq ab
    ```
  - Conversely, however, **not all *expressions* are recognized as such** in argument mode, and therefore situationally require **enclosure in `(...)`**, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--); e.g.:

    ```bash
     # Same as:
     #   @{ prop=1 }, @{ prop=1e12 } |
     #     Where-Object { $_.prop -gt [int]::MaxValue }
     # Note the required (...) around [int]::MaxValue
     @{ prop=1 }, @{ prop=1e12 } | 
       Where-Object prop -gt ([int]::MaxValue)
    ```

---

<sup>[1] Unfortunately, as of PowerShell (Core) 7.4.x you cannot compare the input objects *as a whole*, because the syntax *requires* specifying a property name. E.g. even though something like `1..10 | Where-Object -gt 5` would be useful, it doesn't currently work. See [GitHub issue #8357](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8357) for a feature request that would enable the latter.</sup>

Comment: So, in PowerShell, the left and right hand sides of `-ne` have different meanings?

Comment: I was surprised to find that this needed `{` brackets.

Comment: @J.Mini, not per se, as the solution implies. It is only in the context of the - inherently _limited_ - simplified syntax that there are constraints on what you can specify as the RHS.